# How to remove parameter from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I apologise if this question is asked before but I can't find the specific instance for my problem.

How to achieve this `www.example.com/index.php?user=john` to `www.example.com/john`

I am using this already to remove the `.php` extension but it doesn't fix the user parameter.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]

ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9_]+) ?user=$1
```

I highly value any reply. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess rules. Considering that you have to pass your arguments to index.php file in backend.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/index\.php\?user=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite rules here..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thank you for reply, but this adds directory

Comment: @unobatbayar, as mentioned in answer, could you please do let me know if you have index.php in your folder? OR which file you want to serve url from backend?

Comment: oh sorry. yes, there is index.php file. And in this file we check the user GET parameter @ravindersingh13

Comment: @unobatbayar, please do check my updated rules and let me know how it goes?

Comment: thank you so much for helping but same result :/

Comment: @unobatbayar, it should work, what is the Error you are seeing?

Comment: I tested in localhost and website environment 10 times now, it doesn't work. It's adding directory information before the name and localhost/example.com

Comment: @unobatbayar, ok, I have edited my rules now, could you please do check it once and let me know if these help now?

Comment: Still doesn't work. The problem seems to be here RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: @unobatbayar, ok this rule expects that your htaccess and index.php are in same folder, could you please confirm the same once.

Comment: yes .htaccess file and index.php are both in the same folder htdocs/ and public_html/

Comment: @unobatbayar, ok what is the url you are hitting here? may be we need to set rewritebase here? Just add line `RewriteBase /example.com/` after 1st line and try once.

Comment: @unobatbayar, so what's your complete path of htaccess and index.php where they are situated in server? `Users/administrator/Desktop/konple` is this the path taken from previous comments.

Comment: @unobatbayar, yes it has to do in some cases we may need to some additional settings in htaccess rules, that's why I am asking.